# Tkinter Scrollbar and Menu crashing for no reason

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to make a simple GUI with tkinter in Python 2.7. Yesterday it was working perfectly, but today it crashes for a very odd error:

```
sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
NameError: name 'RIGHT' is not defined
```

When I remove the arguments, there still is another error quite similar:

```
menubar=Menu(mgui)
NameError: name 'Menu' is not defined
```

I have no idea why this happens, why it stopped working. I'm not sure if it's because the code is wrong or maybe the tools I'm working with are.

Here's the code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
from ScrolledText import *

mgui=tk.Tk()
mgui.geometry('700x450')
mgui.title('Adminstrador de ntoas')
mtitle=tk.StringVar()
mtext=tk.StringVar()
sbar = tk.Scrollbar(mgui)
sbar.pack()    

menubar=Menu(mgui)

def donothing():
   filewin = Toplevel(mgui)
   button = Button(filewin, text="Do nothing button")
   button.pack()

def llama_crea_notebook():
    cng_gui=tk.Toplevel(width=700,height=200)
    cng_gui.title("Generado de Notebooks")


filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Create Notebook", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Change Notebook", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command=quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

notemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
notemenu.add_command(label="Read Note", command=donothing)
notemenu.add_command(label="Delete Note", command=donothing)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Note", menu=notemenu)

helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="Manual", command=donothing)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=donothing)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
```

Comment: What do you mean "crashing for no reason"? It's clearly giving you a reason.

Comment: Update: The problem with the code was that Tkinter wasn't working on a global level, so I modified the code in order to correct the errors caused by that. However, with the new changes, I'm now generating an empty window, that's to say, there is no menu.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yeah, I think I didn't express myself correctly, what I meant was that yesterday it wasn't crashing yet today did. On hindsight, I don't know why it worked yesterday at all, it should have prompted me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import the `tkinter` module as `import Tkinter as tk`, that means that for everything you want to access from `tkinter` must be done as

```
tk.<something>
```

`Button`, `Menu`, `RIGHT`... all belong to `tkinter`. Solution: replace `import Tkinter as tk` with `from Tkinter import *`.

However, using `tk.<something>` is more readable so I would advise that option.

Comment: Thank you ofr your response. I added the "tk." to everything that was missing it, but now it displays an empty window, with no signs of the menu.

Comment: @BrianJohnson add `mgui.config(menu=menubar)` before `mgui.mainloop()`

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get those errors are that they're written as if there was a:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

line. Instead you have a more readable:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

Thus, neither `RIGHT`, nor `Menu` is defined in the global namespace. Use:

```
sbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
```

and

```
menubar=tk.Menu(mgui)
```

instead. There are other several similar issues with `Toplevel` and `Button` calls.

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't know about the Toplevel and Button calls problem if you hadn't told me.